# Big book (328 pages), XeLaTeX compilation: OK with TeXLive 2017, KO with TL 2018, OK with only 100 pages

Tags: xetex, pdf, texlive-2018

Since TeXLive 2018, my books (all of them, not a special one) compile (XeLaTeX) without special errors, the PDF file display correctly with Acrobat Reader, but with Evince or Xpdf the answer is “the PDF file is damaged”.

With TeXLive 2017 everything is OK. If I take only a few chapters (about 100 pages) everything is OK (hence no MWE possible :-().

After a lot of attempts, I suspect a font problem, but with only lmodern the result is the same. Underneath this message is the diff between the two \listfiles outputs. The log files are too big, so I don't post them.

## Here is the diff between the two \listfiles outputs:

```
2c2
<   memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document cl
---
>   memoir.cls    2018/04/04 v3.7g configurable book, report, article document cl
5c5
<   ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
---
>   ifetex.sty    2018/03/31 v1.2a ifetex
9d8
< mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
11,14c10,13
< fontspec.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
<   xparse.sty    2018/02/21 L3 Experimental document command parser
<    expl3.sty    2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (loader) 
< expl3-code.tex    2018/02/21 L3 programming layer 
---
> fontspec.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
>   xparse.sty    2018-05-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
>    expl3.sty    2018-06-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
> expl3-code.tex    2018-06-14 L3 programming layer 
16c15,16
< fontspec-xetex.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
---
> fontspec-xetex.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
> 
33c33
<  minitoc.sty    2015/07/13 v61 Package minitoc
---
>  minitoc.sty    2018/07/12 v62 Package minitoc
50,51c50,51
< pstricks.tex    2018/01/06 v2.82 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
<   pst-fp.tex    2018/01/06 v2.82 `PST-fp' (hv)
---
> pstricks.tex    2018/07/22 v2.85 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
>   pst-fp.tex    2018/07/22 v2.85 `PST-fp' (hv)
65,67c65,67
< csquotes.sty    2018/02/11 v5.2c context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
< etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
< csquotes.def    2018/02/11 v5.2c csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
---
> csquotes.sty    2018/04/13 v5.2d context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
> etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
> csquotes.def    2018/04/13 v5.2d csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
86c86
< pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
---
> pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
109c109
< biblatex.sty    2017/12/19 v3.10 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
---
> biblatex.sty    2018/03/04 v3.11 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
114,116c114
<   blx-dm.def
<  numeric.dbx
< biblatex-dm.cfg
---
>   blx-dm.def    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
118,122c116,120
< blx-compat.def    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
< biblatex.def    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
< standard.bbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
<  numeric.bbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
<  numeric.cbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
---
> blx-compat.def    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
> biblatex.def    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
> standard.bbx    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
>  numeric.bbx    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
>  numeric.cbx    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
126c124
<   french.lbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
---
>   french.lbx    2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
449c447,450
< Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 163.
---
> Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 163.
> Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `CoursScheme-Manuel_2019-03-25.out' has not c
> hanged.
> (rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 075E04BDD245C7C5C39962DBCC4EE089.
```

==============

If a distinguished member of the list had any hint, I would be very grateful.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you able to use `lipsum` or `blindtext` to make a long enough example to run into the problem?  If it's truly a problem with the number of pages, you could have 3 inch margins to help those packages get to that many pages sooner.  That would also help narrow down if the problem is the number of pages, the size of the file, or something else.

Comment: NEVER a suggestion to mix cls or sty HOWEVER in your case you could try one by  one placing copies of newer sty/cls in a PERSONAL texmf OR the TEX FOLDER run with 2017 AND older sty/cls files run with 2018 just to try and isolate a single culprit (beware could introduce red herrings so test all)  IF that works to reduce to a single candidate then those that know that/those package{s} may have a better handle on why

Comment: What do you get for messages from xdvipdfmx if you compile  `xelatex --no-pdf file` and `xdvipdfmx -vv file`?

Comment: Common issues are bad auxillary files from one run may affect all subsequent runs try minimum set of files in a fresh simple folder (no accents spaces etc) root/cleantex/ Also if using {hyperref} move lower after other packages. You could as mwe post your preamble especially if it has a common order for package loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, eventually I've found a solution: Ubuntu's TeXLive is in some way not correct. I've erased it and installed TeXLive directly from https://www.tug.org/texlive/, and now everything is (apparently) correct.